# MS access >2gb and inaccessible: Can't be repaired followed by 'Object invalid or no longer set'

Tags: ms-access

We have added 2 queries that should drop and load tables into our DB. For an (at this time) untracable 'mistake', it is likely that the queries only loaded and did not drop any tables to end up with a DB over 2GB. At first, the debugger showed the line of the loading query, but after a restart Access gives the error "Can't be repaired", followed by the error "Object invalid or no longer set".

I have tried numerous workarounds in order to compact the DB from excel using DAO, various repair tools (which did not return the forms and reports) but still I do not have my complete database back.

Do you have any further suggestions on how I can save this DB?

Comment: If database file size exceeds 2 Gb then it is damaged till unrecoverable state. Restore your database from backup. There exists some third-party tools which may restore the data from such file partially, of course... but no way to restore fully - because a part of data is overwritten with another part of data.

Comment: We were able to use a paid tool in order to repair.

Comment: None tool can recover all. It's impossible to recover the information which not exists.